# Is there a way to assign multiple labels per vertex in R

Tags: r, label, igraph

I'm brand new to R and currently am stuck while working on a social network. I'm using the package igraph to create the network. 
The way I'm calling for the plot is:

```
 plot(k, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, vertex.label=V(k)$Rank)
```

Is it possible to have multiple labels on a vertex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use paste to concatenate the labels together. Here I choose dummy labels ,

```
labe is  lower letter:UPPER LETTER


library(igraph)
g <- graph.ring(5)
V(g)$size <- 100
V(g)$label=paste(letters[1:5],LETTERS[1:5],sep=':')
V(g)$label.cex <- 2
plot(g)
```

[image]